# Mongo : Trouble updating a Mongo DB row

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update a row in Mongo DB .
I have a  collection named users

```
db.users.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e2efe968caee13be412413"), "username" : "sss", "age" : 32 }
```

**I am trying to update the row with the username as Erinamodobo and modify the age to 55**

I have tried the below way , but its not working .

```
db.users.update({ "_id": "50e2efe968caee13be412413" }, { $set: { "username": "Erinamodobo" } });
```

Please let me know where i am making the mistake ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the _id as an ObjectId if you're using the mongo shell, otherwise, it won't find the existing user.

```
db.users.update({"_id": ObjectId("50e2efe968caee13be412413")},
     { "$set" :
          { "username": "Erinamodobo", "age" : "55" }})
```

Answer (score 1):

With this query you are updating the name itself.

Notice that the syntax of an update is the following:

```
 db.COLLECTION.update( {query}, {update}, {options} )
```

where `query` selects the record to update and `update` specify the value of the field to update.

So, in your case the correct command is:

```
 db.users.update({ "name": "Erinamodobo" }, { $set: { "age": 55 } });
```

However, I suggets you to read the mongodb documentation, is very well written (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/)

Comment: (I added an answer based on the _id as I didn't understand your answer.) Now I see it:  Your update command would have worked if the query portion had matched his original data. It would have needed to be `{"username" : "sss"}`, although that of course would have matched all usernames with `sss` as their value (which may have not been desired).

Comment: thats okay i modified that , and thanks very much for the  concern shown

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to @WiredPrairie, even though he states the right answer he doesn't really explain.

The `OjbectId` is not a string, it is actually a `Object` so to search by that `Object` you must supply an `Ojbect` of the same type, i.e. here an `ObjectId`:

```
db.users.update({ "_id": ObjectId("50e2efe968caee13be412413") }, { $set: { "username": "Erinamodobo" } });
```

The same goes for any specific BSON type you use from `Date` to `NumberLong` you will need to wrap the parameters in `Object`s of the type.